# SP 2016 branding on-premises?

Tags: sharepoint-server, branding

We have SharePoint 2016 server. Anyone who has experience about branding in SharePoint 2016 on-premises please?

I want to change the logo and current navigation.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. This is too broad of a topic.

Comment: @ Trevor thanks for prompt respond I need to change the logo and current navigation?

Comment: Yes, but are you looking to use PowerShell to create a few current navigation entries and add a logo to each site (or use the GUI to achieve the same thing), or create a full-blown branding solution, or somewhere in between? The more detail that you can provide about exactly what you're trying to achieve the better as it will help others answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use powershell to change these. I pulled it from [this article](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/10/customize-suitebar-text-link-in-sharepoint-2016-using-powershell.html).

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$WebApp= Get-SPWebApplication "http://intranet.crescent.com"
$WebApp.SuiteNavBrandingText = "Crescent Portal"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl = "/_layouts/images/dot_ruleper.gif"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle = "Crescent Logo"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl = "http://portal.crescent.com"
$webapp.Update()
```